# Adding Metadata for Fungible SPL tokens (Metaplex)

Tags: spl-token, metaplex, metadata

I'm trying to add metadata for a fungible SPL token, which was done via token-list before.
I have tried using strata protocol, but it does not show up on the list so cannot be done. Is there a simple js codeblock or CLI command to add the metadata easily?

Comment: On Strata just paste the mint address and it will work

Answer (score 2):

To create metadata account on any SPL token you can create use version 2 of `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata@2`.

Version 3 exists, but is significantly more complex.

```
npm i "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata@2"
```

```
const createMetadataAccount = async (
  metadataPDA: PublicKey,
  mint: PublicKey,
  payer: PublicKey,
  metadataData: any
) => {
  const tx = new Transaction().add(
    createCreateMetadataAccountV2Instruction(
      {
        metadata: metadataPDA,
        mint: mint,
        mintAuthority: payer,
        payer: payer,
        updateAuthority: payer,
      },
      {
        createMetadataAccountArgsV2: {
          data: metadataData,
          isMutable: true,
        },
      }
    )
  );
  return tx;
};
```

To get the metadata PDA

```
const TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID = new PublicKey(
  "metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s"
);

const getMetadata = async (mint: PublicKey): Promise<PublicKey> => {
  return (
    await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
      [
        Buffer.from("metadata"),
        TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(),
        mint.toBuffer(),
      ],
      TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID
    )
  )[0];
};
```

The data part which is being passed in instruction looks like:

```
const metadataData = {
  name: "Test Token",
  symbol: "Test",
  uri: uri, // Arweave URI link which uses metaplex standard
  sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
  creators: null,
  collection: null,
  uses: null,
};
```

Creating the transaction and passing the parameters :

```
const addMetadata = (mintAddress: PublicKey, connection: Connection) => {
  const payer = Keypair.fromSecretKey(
    new Uint8Array(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(keypair, { encoding: "utf8" })))
  );
  const metadataAccount = await getMetadata(mintAddress);
  const tx = await createMetadataAccount(
    metadataAccount,
    mintAddress,
    payer,
    metadataData
  );
  const transactionId = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, tx);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Metaboss to create an SPL-Token with Metadata or add Metadata to an existing token.

https://metaboss.rs/create.html

**Metadata**

Decorate an existing SPL token mint with metadata.

**Usage**

Specify the existing mint address and path to a metadata file that contains the name, symbol and uri fields in a JSON format.

```
metaboss create metadata -a <mint_address> -m <metadata_file>
```