# How do I mint an SPL token with custom Metadata without using the Metaplex JS SDK?

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, metadata, javascript, typescript

> Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69701491/add-meta-data-to-solana-token-with-solana-web3-js, however, the only answer for that question is in Rust and the question asker ended up moving to eth instead!

I know I can create an NFT with SPL:

```
const mint = await createMint(
  connection,
  wallet,
  wallet.publicKey,
  wallet.publicKey,
  0
);
```

Or with Metaplex:

```
const metaplexNFTs = Metaplex.make(connection)
  .use(keypairIdentity(keypair))
  .use(bundlrStorage())
  .nfts()

createOutput = await metaplexNFTs.create(
  {
    uri: metadataURL,
    name: "Some token name", <- I'd like to be able to add 'name' but also other metadata with @solana/spl-token
    sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0, 
  }
);
```

But can I create an NFT with custom data **just using web3.js and spl-token, not `@metaplex-foundation/js`?**

- [Metaplex's metadata is focused on art NFTs (eg with images etc) rather than non-art NFTs](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2780/need-assistance-creating-a-custom-type-of-nft).
- `@metaplex-foundation/js` is pre 1.0 software that changes very frequently
- I would like to avoid using extra software if I can.

**How do I mint an SPL token with custom Metadata using @solana/web3.js and @solana/spl-token?**

Update: I found [this answer in my research so I know it's possible](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2780/need-assistance-creating-a-custom-type-of-nft):

> Create an SPL token first with supply = 1 and decimal = 0 so the wallets can identify your asset (done, easy!)
>
> Create another account preferably derived from the mint address of your SPL token using PDAs
>
> Finally, save your custom metadata in the second account and use it in any way you need.

I just need help or a pointer to the right docs. I am comfortable adding instructions to a larger transaction with `new Transaction().add()` etc. Just need to know what to add!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll still end up needing to use metaplex since metaplex controls the Token Metadata Program. Specifically, you'll need to use `createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction` from `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata`

https://metaplex-foundation.github.io/metaplex-program-library/docs/token-metadata/index.html#createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction

You can use `@solana/spl-token` to create a mint like you mentioned, and then `@solana/web3.js` to built and send a transaction.

Comment: Thanks @john! Main thing I was concerned about was avoiding the Metaplex JS SDK `@metaplex-foundation/js`, happy to use the on-chain Metaplex program (I've edited the question to make this clear). I ended up finding `createCreateMetadataAccountV3Instruction()` myself (see my answer below), but since you're not me and you found the answer I'll mark this one as correct,

Answer (score 3):

**Answering my own question to help others** based on [Adding Metadata for Fungible SPL tokens (Metaplex)](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3156/adding-metadata-for-fungible-spl-tokens-metaplex) and [Need assistance creating a custom type of NFT](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2780/need-assistance-creating-a-custom-type-of-nft), updating deprecated function signatures, and some other research.

Plain `spl-token`, no `@metaplex-foundation/js`. Using a single function from `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata` though but `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata` seems to be more stable than `@metaplex-foundation/js`.

```
import {
  Transaction,
  type PublicKey,
  PublicKey as PublicKeyConstructor,
  Connection,
  Keypair,
  sendAndConfirmTransaction,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import {
  createCreateMetadataAccountV2Instruction,
  type DataV2,
} from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";
import { log } from "console";
import { Buffer } from "buffer";
import { createMint } from "@solana/spl-token";

// Use a read URL for your connection, and a real user.
const connection = new Connection("...");
const steve = new Keypair();

const METAPLEX_TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ADDRESS =
  "metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s";

const metaplexTokenMetadataProgram = new PublicKeyConstructor(
  METAPLEX_TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ADDRESS
);

const createMetadataAccount = async (
  metadataPDA: PublicKey,
  mint: PublicKey,
  payer: PublicKey,
  metadataData: any
) => {
  const transaction = new Transaction().add(
    createCreateMetadataAccountV2Instruction(
      {
        metadata: metadataPDA,
        mint: mint,
        mintAuthority: payer,
        payer: payer,
        updateAuthority: payer,
      },
      {
        createMetadataAccountArgsV2: {
          data: metadataData,
          isMutable: true,
        },
      }
    )
  );
  return transaction;
};

const getMetadataPDA = (mint: PublicKey): PublicKeyConstructor => {
  return PublicKeyConstructor.findProgramAddressSync(
    [
      Buffer.from("metadata"),
      metaplexTokenMetadataProgram.toBuffer(),
      mint.toBuffer(),
    ],
    metaplexTokenMetadataProgram
  )[0];
};

// Doesn't have to be DataV2, if you're not making art NFTs
const metadata: DataV2 = {
  name: "Portal Recovery Token",
  symbol: "Test",
  uri: "", // Arweave URI link which uses metaplex standard if you're making art NFTs
  sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
  creators: null,
  collection: null,
  uses: null,
};

const addMetadata = async (mintAddress: PublicKey, connection: Connection) => {
  const metadataAccount = await getMetadataPDA(mintAddress);
  const transactionToSend = await createMetadataAccount(
    metadataAccount,
    mintAddress,
    steve.publicKey,
    metadata
  );
  const transactionId = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
    connection,
    transactionToSend,
    [steve]
  );
  log(transactionId);
};

const mintNFT = async () => {
  // Create a SPL token first with supply = 1 and decimal = 0 so the wallets can identify your asset (done, easy!)
  const mintAddress = await createMint(
    connection,
    steve,
    steve.publicKey,
    steve.publicKey,
    0
  );
  // Create another account preferably derived from the mint address of your SPL token using PDAs
  // Finally, save your custom metadata in the second account and use it in any way you need.
  // To create metadata account on any SPL token you can create using (JS version)
  const transactionId = await addMetadata(mintAddress, connection);
};
```

Comment: createMetadataAccountArgsV2 is not defined

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit dated, but some example code from Strata if nobody else posts a full answer:

https://github.com/StrataFoundation/strata/blob/master/packages/marketplace-ui/src/components/form/ManualForm.tsx#L66

Comment: Thanks, that uses `"@strata-foundation/react"` to do most of the work, so it's not quite the minimal spl and web3.js answer I was hoping for, I can dive into there to see how that works though...

Answer (score 1):

I found that the easiest way for me was to create the token via spl-token CLI then add metadata via metaboss (https://metaboss.rs/create.html) You can also use metaboss for both tasks (creating then adding metadata)